# Some conversion questions for C++

Tags: c++, char, int, type-conversion

I'm doing a distributed program(I'm don't know if this is the word, I learned in spanish), where I need to send and receive messages between some processes, pretty simple at first sight.

It gets complicated when I want to send two ints in the same message. With send() you can only send char* so I used this:

```
string s = to_string(valla) + " " + to_string(tiempo);
const char* buffNum = s.c_str();
```

All good until I have to receive and 'decode' the message. So if I receive one single number I can use atoi(), now the question is, how do I do this when I receive two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Answer (score 6):

```
const char* buffNum = s.c_str();
```

yields undefined behaviour dereferencing `buffNum`, as soon `s` is changed or goes out of scope.

---

To *decode* if you're sure your string is fine, use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream iss(buffNum);

int num1, num2;

iss >> num1 >> num2;
```

Comment: `buffNum` and `s` are fine. Can you please elaborate on the use of  `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @dari1495 What you don't understand in particular?

Comment: no problem, I see you edited with an example, all clear now, thanks

Comment: I have a problem now, when I receive the message it's actually `char buffNum[100]` and the compiler says that the type is incomplete :(

Comment: @dari1495 Completely unrelated problem. Ask another question please. Don't forget to provide a [MCVE] that enables everyone to reproduce your problem, and show error messages verbatim in your new question.